# Adblockers are blocking mod_pagespeed_beacon, Can I prevent this on the server side (Apache)?

Tags: apache, mod-pagespeed

I would like to prevent Adblockers from blocking `mod_pagespeed_beacon` on the server side (Apache) since mod_pagespeed is not used for advertisements..
Is this possible? If so, How?

*Note: I've already informed uBlock Origin about this issue and they are aware of it. Meanwhile, I would like to solve this on the server side if possible.*

`uBlock Origin` blocking a mod_pagespeed_beacon request:
[image: uBlock Origin blocking mod_pagespeed]

Comment: Does the information in this link help answer your question? https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/filter-instrumentation-add#beacon_url